# How to avoid "FrameBuffer" error in Ubuntu Touch Emulator?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

When I boot into Ubuntu touch, it gives me the following error and hangs:

> "FrameBuffer::post eglMakeCurrent failed"

It only happens when I'm using my propreitary display driver.

So I understand this is likely to be a driver related issue which is beyond the control of Canonical. Hence **I'm seeking a workaround to avoid this**. (Maybe by disabling gpu rendering in the emulator?)

This situation is very uncomfortable when it comes to app development.

> Ubuntu Touch Version : Trusty Thar
>   Host OS : Trusty Thar
>   ubuntu-emulator version: 0.2+14.10.20140429.1-0ubuntu1
>   My GPU : AMD Mobility Radeon HD 5430

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Here are four options are suggested.

**1. Temporary disable framebuffer in GRUB boot menu**

Making this change will have no impact on your installed system and is to be considered safe. If you reboot your system this change will disappear. It is temporary.

Start your computer normally and after a few seconds you will see the GRUB boot loader menu.

Start your computer normally and after a few seconds you will see the GRUB boot loader menu.

- With the use of the arrow keys, highlight the title of your choice you want to edit (the first Ubuntu entry should be ok) and press "e" to go to the entry editor interface. You will now see the boot entries for the title you selected.
- Highlight, again with the use of the arrow keys, the line that say "kernel" and press "e" to edit that line.
- Add, without the quotes " vga=normal nomodeset" and press the enter key to go out of edit mode.
- Press the "b" key to boot your system.

**Note:** To cancel your changes press the Escape key until the main menu appear.

---

**2. Permanently disable framebuffer in GRUB config file**

See "Setting different framebuffer resolutions in GRUB" below.

---

**3. Disable the framebuffer in CMOS/BIOS**
Making this change will have no impact on your installed system. However, the change will remain until you change the setting back.

This wiki will not go into the details of this option for a very simple reason; many systems have different BIOS and versions of it. How you enter your BIOS and where to make the change can differ quite alot.

- Enter your BIOS
- Find the framebuffer reference and disable it
- Save your settings and reboot the system
- Boot your Ubuntu system normally

---

**4. Disable framebuffer at install time**

When installing your Ubuntu system, you can tell the Ubuntu installer not to use the framebuffer. Type F6 at the Start Menu then add without the quotes "vga=711" and press the enter key.

---

**Setting different framebuffer resolutions in old versions of GRUB**

**note:** *Modern versions of GRUB build their configuration files from pieces kept under `/etc/grub.d/` and in the parameter file `/etc/default/grub`. To make changes to modern GRUB, you will need to learn how to make changes to the `/etc/default/grub` file, and then run `update-grub` to create the new GRUB configuration file `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`. The changes described below to `menu.lst` only work for older versions of GRUB.*

In the configuration file for GRUB `/boot/grub/menu.lst` you can set a different resolution for, or disable, the framebuffer.

The option you must add to the "kernel ..." row for your selected menu item is "vga=value" (without the quotes).

- adding "vga=normal" or "nofb" to the kernel line disables the framebuffer
- if "nofb" does not help, try "nomodeset" to disable kernel mode setting
- adding "vga=ask" will enable you to set a value at each boot - good for testing out the various modes.

So, to disable the framebuffer, enter "vga=normal", or "nofb" to the kernel line of the active kernel that you are using in menu.lst and then reboot. You will need to re-edit the menu.lst file every time you update the kernel version or GRUB itself. These changes will disable the framebuffer for ONLY this specific GRUB entry; to disable them for all kernels see below.

Example (old versions of GRUB only):

```
title           Ubuntu, kernel 2.6.15-20-386
root            (hd0,4)
kernel          /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.15-20-386 root=/dev/hda5 ro nofb
initrd          /boot/initrd.img-2.6.15-20-386
savedefault
boot
```

For other resolutions, here is a list:

```
Colour depth        640x480     800x600     1024x768    1280x1024   1400x1050   1600x1200
8  (256)        769     771     773     775             
15 (32K)        784     787     790     793             
16 (65K)        785     788     791     794     834     884
24 (16M)        786     789     792     795
```

So, to use the framebuffer with 16 bit colour depth at a resolution of 1024x768 you would add "vga=791" (again without quotes) to the kernel line (the active kernel that you are using - you will need to re-edit menu.lst every time you update the kernel version). Example:

```
title           Ubuntu, kernel 2.6.15-20-386
root            (hd0,4)
kernel          /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.15-20-386 root=/dev/hda5 ro vga=791
initrd          /boot/initrd.img-2.6.15-20-386
savedefault
boot
```

**Simply Disabling the Framebuffer in the menu.lst file for all kernels**

One can alter the menu.lst file to disable the framebuffer for all kernels, and all new kernels. Edit the `/boot/grub/menu.lst` file with whatever editor you prefer, with sudo rights. Be sure to backup your original just in case you really mess things up.

```
sudo cp /boot/grub/menu.lst  /boot/grub/menu.list.backup_date
sudo nano /boot/grub/menu.lst
```

We are interested in the following lines. The Last Line is the one that needs to be changed. Note that unlike other config files 2 comments ## marks are actually a comment for Grub and the update-grub command. One # is just a comment for grub, but IS a configuration line for the update-grub command. Be very careful to leave the # of #'s correct.

```
## additional options to use with the default boot option, but not with the
## alternatives
## e.g. defoptions=vga=791 resume=/dev/hda5
## The following Line is the default for all kernels. Yours may vary the nofb option disables the framebuffer
## the nosplash option also disables the fancy splash screen. You may want to disable this to allow easier troubleshooting of the system
# defoptions=quiet nosplash nofb
```

Once the last line is edited as you like. You need to run the update-grub command with root rights in order for all the grub kernel entries to be fixed with the new options.

`sudo update-grub`

Now the framebuffer should be disabled for all current and new kernels.

**Other Framebuffer tools and tweaks**

*This section needs to be expanded *

Most of this wiki has been on how to disable the framebuffer, It does have some actual use however. Some things the framebuffer device allows include. 
-video playback on the console without need for the X system being installed. 
-some games can use the framebuffer 
-customization of the console background to include logos and other images 
-image viewers with out the need for X to be installe. 
-X can even be configured to use the framebuffer device instead of a specific video card driver.

If one does wish to use and explore the framebuffer, the `fbset` command allows one to change several settings of the framebuffer on the fly.

`sudo apt-get install fbset`

To see other applications that have framebuffer features (not a complete list) the following will get you started.

`apt-cache search framebuffer | less`

Mplayer, and other players can also have framebuffer support.

~[Source](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FrameBuffer#How_to_disable_the_framebuffer)~